# Image Upload Script Error

Tags: php, html, image

I'm using this php code for an image upload. But I keep getting an error towards the end. The result "Error while uploading image. Please Try Again. I feel like I have checked everything but the dang image just wont copy into the uimages folder. Please help...

Here is the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php 

function create_thumbnail($source,$destination,$thumb_width){

    $size = getimagesize($source);
    $width = $size[0];
    $height = $size[1];
    $x = 0;
    $y = 0;

    if($width > $height){

        $x = ceil(($width - $height) / 2);
        $width = $height;
        }
            else if($height> $width){
            $y =(($height - $width) /2);
            $height = $width;
}

$new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($thumb_width,$thumb_height) or die('Cannot Initiatlize new GD image stream');

$extension = get_image_extension($source);
if($extension=='jpg' || $extension=='jpeg')
    $image= imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
if($extension=='gif')
    $image= imagecreatefromgif($source);
if($extension=='png')
    $image= imagecreatefrompng($source);


imagecopyresampled($new_image,$image,0,0,$x,$y,$thumb_width,$thumb_width,$width,$height);
if($extension=='jpg' || $extension=='jpeg')
    imagejpeg($new_image,$destination);
if($extension=='gif')
    imagegif($new_image,$destination);
if($extension=='png')
    imagepng($new_image,$destination);

}

function get_image_extension($name){
    $name=strtolower($name);
    $i = strrpos($name,".");
    if(!$i) {return "";}
        $l = strlen($name) - $i;
        $extension = substr($name,$i+1,$l);
        return $extension;  
    }

function random_name($length){
    $characters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    $name = "";

    for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++){
        $name .= $characters[mt_rand(0,strlen($characters) - 1)];

        }
        return "image-".$name;

    }   

    $images_location = "images";
    $thumbs_location ="uimages/thumbs";
    $thumb_width = 100;
    $maximum_size = 5120;

    $results = "Click to browse to locate the image you want to upload.";

    if($_POST){
        if($_FILES['image']['name'] == "")
{
    $results="No Image Selected. Click Browse to find an image";

    }   
    else{
        $size=filesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
        $filename = stripslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
        $extension = get_image_extension($filename);
        if($size> $maximum_size){
            $results="Your file exceeds the maximum size.";

            }
        else
        if(($extension != "jpg") && ($extension != "jpeg") && ($extension != "png") && ($extension != "gif")){
            $results="Invalid image type. Must be jpg, jpeg, png, or a gif file.";
            }
            else{
                $image_random_name = random_name(15).".".$extension;
    $copy= @copy($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $images_location.$image_random_name);

if(!$copy){
    $results = "Error while uploading image. Please try again.";}
    else{
        create_thumbnail($images_location.$image_random_name,$thumbs_location.$image_random_name,$thumb_width);
        $results="Image has been uploaded";

        }

    }


                }
        }   



?>
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="5120" >
<input type="file" name="image" />
<input type="submit" value="Upload Image" />
</form>

<?php echo $results; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you tried with multiple images? It could be an illegal character in the filename.

Comment: you would know what the actual error was  if you did not suppress it with @

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving the file like this:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $images_location.$image_random_name))
{
    //success
}
else
{
    //fail
}
```

Also check that the target location exists and is being set correctly, and that permissions of the target location are correct- Ensure that apache (or whatever is running) has the correct write access. To set the permissions for apache it is something like this:

```
chown -R nobody directory_name
chmod 755 -R directory_name
```

Comment: Yeppp that was it...FML I checked the code a million times didn't even consider rewriting the permissions...dammit.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i use the following code which works smoothly for images uploading. Check it and use it if you like. Let me know.

```
  <?php if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) 
  { // Handle the form.

if (isset($_FILES['image'])) 
{

    function getExtension($str) 
    {
         $i = strrpos($str,".");
         if (!$i) { return ""; }
         $l = strlen($str) - $i;
         $ext = substr($str,$i,$l);
         return $ext;
    }

    function getName($str) 
    {
         $i = strrpos($str,".");
         if (!$i) { return ""; }
         $l = strlen($str) - $i;
         $name = substr($str,0,$i);
         return $name;
    }

    $image=$_FILES['image']['name'];
    //if it is not empty
    if ($image) 
    {
    //get the original name of the file from the clients machine
        $filename = stripslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
    //get the extension of the file in a lower case format
        $extension = getExtension($filename);
        $name = getName($filename);

        $extension = strtolower($extension);
    //if it is not a known extension, we will suppose it is an error and will not  upload the file,  
    //otherwise we will do more tests
        if (($extension != ".jpg") && ($extension != ".jpeg") && ($extension != ".png") && ($extension != ".gif")) 
        {
        //print error message
            echo '<p class="error">Please upload a JPEG, GIF or PNG image.</p>';
        }
        else
        {
            if ($_FILES['image']['error'] > 0) 
            {
                echo '<p class="error">The file could not be uploaded because: <strong>';

                // Print a message based upon the error.
                switch ($_FILES['image']['error']) 
                {
                    case 1:
                        print 'The file exceeds the upload_max_filesize setting in php.ini.';
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        print 'The file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE setting in the HTML form.';
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        print 'The file was only partially uploaded.';
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        print 'No file was uploaded.';
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        print 'No temporary folder was available.';
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        print 'Unable to write to the disk.';
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        print 'File upload stopped.';
                        break;
                    default:
                        print 'A system error occurred.';
                        break;
                } // End of switch.

                print '</strong></p>';

            } // End of error IF.   
            else
            {
                // Query the database:
                $q = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE user_id='{$_SESSION["user_id"]}' AND name='$name'";    
                $r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q) or trigger_error("Query: $q\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));

                if (@mysqli_num_rows($r) == 0)
                { // A match was made.

                $q = "INSERT INTO images (user_id, title, name, extension, profile, date_uploaded) VALUES ('{$_SESSION["user_id"]}', '$name', '$name', '$extension', 'no', NOW() )";
                $r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q) or trigger_error("Query: $q\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));

                    if (mysqli_affected_rows($dbc) == 1) 
                    {
                        //we will give an unique name, for example the time in unix time format
                        $image_name = $name . $extension;
                        //the new name will be containing the full path where will be stored (images folder)
                        $newname = "../uploads/".$_SESSION["user_id"]."/".$image_name;
                        //we verify if the image has been uploaded, and print error instead
                        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $newname);

                        // Delete the file if it still exists:
                        if (file_exists ($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']) && is_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']) ) 
                        {
                            unlink ($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo '<p class="error">aaa You could not upload pictures due to a system error. We apologize for any inconvenience.</p>';
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    echo '<p class="error">This picture is already uloaded. Choose another.</p>';   
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
?>

<h2>Upload More Pics of You</h2>
<form id="upload_image" name="upload_image" method="post" action="upload_image.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<table width="318" border="0" cellpadding="0" align="left">
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center">Select a JPEG, GIF or PNG image of you <br />(512KB or smaller) to be uploaded:</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="47" align="right">Image:</td>
    <td width="265">
    <input type="file" name="image" id="image" /><input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="524288"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center" colspan="2"><span class="art-button-wrapper">
            <span class="l"> </span>
            <span class="r"> </span>
            <input class="art-button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /><input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="TRUE" />
        </span></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```